# Segmentcontrol in tableviewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I got this tableview with segmented controls in each cell. I get some data from my database that i put into the cells segmented control. But how to set no segment chosen? If noting is found in the database it returns -1. I tried the: `segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = -1;`, but with no luck. It looks like it set the `segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;`, be course segment with index 0 is selected no matter what (even if i get a result or not). See screenshots to understand :)

Btw I can select as many segments as I want in each segmented control..
Why is this possible? Will the other problem fix this? :)

THANK YOU!

My code for creating the cells is:

```
  UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
  cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"StateCell"];
  if (cell == nil)
  {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseI dentifier:@"StateCell"];
  }

  UIImage *correctImageGreen = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
  UIImage *correctImageGul = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"gul.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
  UIImage *correctImageRed = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"red.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

  NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: correctImageGreen, correctImageGul, correctImageRed, nil];
  UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];

 segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(308, 7, 150, 28);

 [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

 int newIndexPath = indexPath.row + 1;
 NSString *indexPathKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", newIndexPath];


 NSString *selectedState = [statefieldData valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"StateField%@", indexPathKey]];
 int selectedIndexInt = [selectedState intValue];

 if (selectedIndexInt == -1) {
     segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = -1;
 } 
 else {
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = selectedIndexInt;
 }

 [cell.contentView addSubview:segmentedControl];

 cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
 cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
 [self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:37 green:37 blue:37 alpha:0]];
 cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


 return cell;
 [[self tableView] reloadData];
```

[image: Screenshot of my problem]

Comment: Hi ! I think a segmentedControl cannot not have a selected segment

Comment: What? Segmentedcontrols is for controlling segments?
There would be no segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = -1; if it not was possible.. If you know what i need to do, please say.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation states:

> **selectedSegmentIndex**
>   The default value is `UISegmentedControlNoSegment` (no segment selected) until the user touches a segment. Set this property to -1 to turn off the current selection.

If you are setting -1 (`UISegmentedControlNoSegment`), and it is *not* deselecting the segment, then there is something else you are doing wrong that we cannot see.

Comment: What could that be?
Im declaring all that have to do with the segmented control in the code above :(

Comment: Are you ensuring that your table view cells are being recycled properly? Ie. have you implemented `-prepareForReuse` in your cell subclass, and ensured that its state is reset?

Comment: I can see that you're not using a cell subclass, and you're adding the segmented control as a new subview each time the cell is returned. With cell reuse, this could end up with your cell having several instances of a segmented control on the view at the same time.

Comment: I would suggest subclassing the table view cell, adding the segmented control as a property, and adding it to the view, and controlling its state rather than creating a new one each time.

Comment: Hi :)
Im very new to this segmented control stuff :(
When you say "adding the segmented control as a property, and adding it to the view" do you mean i need to drag a segmented control into my view controller and then declare as a property? Because i have tried that, and each time the view is opened, it crashes :(

Comment: But please tell me what you would try! ;)